# Stochastic process with non-independent increments

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

All stochastic process I see always have independent increments. It is true for:

- standard brownian motion
- geometric brownian motion (?)
- Ornstein Uhlenbeck (?)
- in general, Levy process

etc.

What are the most common stochastic process used in quant finance that have **dependent** increments, i.e. $X(t+h) - X(t)$ **not independent** from $X(t)$ ?

Answer (score 6):

First thing, **Geometric Brownian motion do not have independent increments**. It is only Wiener process or Brownian motion that have independent increment. Under GBM, the **increments of process (assume stock prices) show markovian property**. It means that changes in the process depend on the current price level. **In layman terms**, the magnitude of change in stock price atleast depend upon existing price level. The probability that stock price will change by \$5 will be different when stock price is \$100, and  when stock price is just \$20.

Same argument also hold true with Ornstein Uhlenbeck. The detail answer of why increments under Ornstein Uhlenbeck are not random is given on [Math S.E](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795797/ornstein-uhlenbeck-process-increments). (Note: The link was first cited by Leon in his answer.)

Now, your question is:

> What are the most common stochastic process used in quant finance that
>   have dependent increments, i.e. $X(t+h)−X(t)$ not independent
>   from $X(t)$

To model such stochastic process where increments are not random, you can use **ARMA class of models**. They are very common in finance and used extensively to **model stock return** and other process(like **interest rate, GDP**, etc.) too.

Comment: It depends on how you define increments though.  GBM, under a transformation, can be described by $X(t+h)-X(t)$ where $X(t+h)-X(t)$ is independent of $X_t$.  There is no such transformation where an OU process can be described in such a way.

Comment: @user9403: Of course independence and increment refers to the original and NOT the transformed variable. Otherwise, it would be a truism that renders the concept and distinction of dependence and independence meaningless, because any two distinct random variables can be made independent by a transformation.

Answer (score 4):

Geometric Brownian Motion has independent increments but Ornstein-Uhlenbeck doesn't have this property.

[For more details you can look here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795797/ornstein-uhlenbeck-process-increments)

Comment: increments under GBM are not independent.

Comment: Ok, sorry for my mistake.

Comment: It is ok @Leon. We all here to lean from each other.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most famous processes with correlated (thus dependent) increments is [Fractional Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Brownian_motion).

In this case
$$
E[B_H(t) B_H (s)]=\frac{1}{2} (|t|^{2H}+|s|^{2H}-|t-s|^{2H}),
$$
where $H$ is a parameter. For $H=1/2$ we get back at uncorrelated increments, thus Brownian motion.

Answer (score 2):

Stochastic time-changed levy processes have uncorrelated increments (which is consistent with "rational" markets) but not independent.  In such a model, volatility is (heuristically) mean reverting while returns are uncorrelated.  The simplest such model is [Heston's model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heston_model).  For a more comprehensive view, see [Carr and Wu's paper](http://faculty.baruch.cuny.edu/lwu/papers/timechangeLevy_JFE2004.pdf).